# Retrieve specific Array from JSON in swift in the form of Array of Keys and Values?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

**JSON** :

```
{
   "11/08/22":[
    {
      "Bill Gates":"Microsoft",
      "Steve Balmer":"Microsoft"
    }],

   "13/08/22":[
    {
      "Tim Cook":"Apple",
      "Jony Ive":"Apple"
    }]

}
```

**Swift Code** :

```
let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
    do {
        if let jsonDate = data, let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonDate, options: []) as? NSDictionary {


            print(jsonResult)

            //Get Result into Seperate Arrays
            let keys = jsonResult.flatMap(){ $0.0 as? String }
            let values = jsonResult.flatMap(){ $0.1 as? String }

        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

})
jsonQuery.resume()
```

**Requirements :**

If i pass from program *"11/08/22"*, I should be able to get all keys and values in the form of **Array of String** of only that array named *"11/08/22"* .

**Better Explanation :**

It should go into 11/08/22 and it should retrieve "Bill Gates","Steve Balmer" as Keys and "Microsoft" As a value in two separate arrays

Comment: What is see is that your JSON contains an array of dictionaries in the key `"11/08/22"`. From where are you expecting an array of strings?

Comment: What (exactly) does the string output you want look like, given input `"11/08/22"`?

Comment: Did you try `jsonResult("11/08/22").flatMap(){ $0.0 as? String }` ?

Comment: I want array of names like " Bill Gates " "Steve Balmer" and different array of company like "Microsoft"

Comment: @Santosh Doesn't work **call value of non-function type 'NSDictionary'**

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov See it should go into 11/08/22 and it should retrieve "Bill Gates","Steve Balmer" as Keys and "Microsoft" As a value in two separate arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let keys=jsonResult["11/08/22"]?.allKeys as? [String];                       
let values=jsonResult["11/08/22"]?.allValues as? [String];
```

It was as simple as this

Answer (score 0):

For this example let's use an array to collect the people and a set to collect the companies:

```
var people: [String] = []
var companies: Set<String> = []
```

Subscript to the JSON dictionary with your "11/08/22" key and cast the result as an array of dictionaries.

Loop over this array and in the loop, add the keys to the people array and insert the values in the companies set.

```
let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
    do {
        if let jsonDate = data, let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonDate, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

            if let dateContent = jsonResult["11/08/22"] as? [[String:String]] {
                for group in dateContent {
                    people.appendContentsOf(group.keys)
                    group.values.forEach { companies.insert($0) }
                }
            }

        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

})
jsonQuery.resume()

print(people)
print(companies)
```

Result:

> ["Steve Balmer", "Bill Gates"]
>   ["Microsoft"]